# PyQt5 GUI for low resolution

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, dpi

How can I automatically scale the GUI made in PyQt5 Designer for low resolution screens? I created the GUI without using layouts, because I didn't know how to properly use them then.

Comment: If the question is "I created a GUI without layouts on a high screen monitor and now I need to resize it, how can I do it?", the answer is: recreate that GUI using layouts.

Comment: I am aware that that is the one solution, but the app is complete now, and it takes too much work to recreate from scratch. I was asking for a workaround. Is there any? @musicamante

Comment: The only workaround would be to *manually* manage resizing from code, based on each widget size hints and policies, which is exactly what layout managers do automatically; that would be a complete mess (and a huge waste of time)  to implement by yourself, especially if you don't have experience with those aspects (and the fact that you didn't use layouts clearly shows that you're not experienced enough for that). So, the answer is: no.

Comment: @musicamante Hm, thank you for quick responses. I was trying to create the app using layouts, but layouts ruin the look of the app. It needs to have "null layout look". But I wasn't able to achieve that with layouts..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "null layout look", but I can tell you from experience that almost any kind of design can be accomplished by using basic layout managers, it's just a matter of expertise (which can only be accomplished after experimentation and deep comprehension). Layouts can be complex, you will probably need to use nested layouts and try different combinations until you find the correct approach, but you'll find that it's worth it. Fixed positions and sizes rarely work properly, and they usually have more issues than benefits.

Comment: @musicamante Yes, I meant to say "Fixed positions and sizes". This is my first time creating GUI and I wasn't aware of layout existence at all.. Even now I am not sure I thoroughly understand how they work. Nevertheless, thank you. :)